# DI injected via constructor class object resolves to null in controller during load test

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.2

In our project we have DI(asp.net core in-built dependency injection) in all controllers via constructor.One controller action invokes a function of a class resolved through the constructor.It has no issues during normal loads.Only when the website is stress tested with about 1000 requests (with ramp 1 second) about 5-10% requests fail with exception thrown as null reference.

[Is it necessary to check null values with constructor injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880470/is-it-necessary-to-check-null-values-with-constructor-injection)
This link suggests that the object in the constructor will never be null ie the framework will throw exception before it reaches the controller scope.

Dependency injection in startup.cs

```
  services.AddSingleton<IRandomInterface , ImplementedClass>();
```

The constructor in the controller :

```
 public RandomController(IRandomInterface wgcr,ILogger<RandomController> log)
 {

            this.object = wgcr;
            this._log = log;

 }
```

The member object in the controller :

```
 private IRandomInterface object { get; set; }
```

The controller action :

```
  [HttpPost("aa")]
  public async Task RandomFunction()
  {

        try
        {  

              if(object ==null)
              {
                    _log.LogInformation("RandomFunction object : null");
              }
              else
                 await object.RandomFunction();



       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

                _log.LogError("error in RandomFunction " + ex.Message "StackTrace " + ex.StackTrace);

        }
  }
```

I cant find a possible reason why the object resolves as null inside the controller without exception being thrown before.If anybody has any insights regarding asp.net core in-built dependency injection would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't shown any code so we can't really help. However, are you absolutely sure the object being injected is null? That sounds very odd.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question @DavidG . I have edited the question with code.Yes regarding your question the log inside the null check clause inside the controller  action gets printed.So I assume it is null here

Comment: And the object is never getting disposed or set to null somewhere else? I feel like there is some code you haven't shown us that is the problem. Can you check the object is null in the constructor perhaps?

Comment: The object is invoked only in one other controller and the usage is similar to the code produced here.Only the object is assigned to a member variable and used to invoke a function.Nowhere in the project is the object made null explicitely.

Comment: Regarding your query,if the object is not getting disposed,we have not explicitely disposed it anywhere.Should that be a reason for the behaviour?

Comment: There's no way based on the code here that `object` can be null. All controller constructor dependencies will be injected with an actual value, or you will get an `InvalidOperationException`. The only way it could be null is if something else is setting it null later on. In that regard, it's always better to use readonly fields, not props, for dependencies: `private readonly IRandomInterface object;`. Then, if something tries to set it null, an exception will be raised. In other words, you can always count on it having a value.

Comment: @Chris Pratt I followed your suggestion but it didn't rectify the issue.I tried null checking in the constructor and surprisingly "object" was not getting null there even though at controller action it was still being null.In my question I mentioned this issue occurs only in stress test.So I scaled up the app service plan in azure where  web app is hosted as an app service.Then for the same load condition the issue didn't happen at all.When app is scaled down,the issue occurs consistently.